# Regular Expression to check first two user inputs and specific length

Tags: regex, validation

I have to validate user inputs which is numbers (8 digits), beginning with 77 and followed by any numbers.
e.g. 
valid inputs
77123456
77281080

invalid inputs
17123456
1728080

All inputs should be followed by 77****** and 8 digits in total.
I tried this ^[0-9]{8}$, this validates the total number of digits to 8.

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:jquery-validate] tag or any other tag that has nothing to do with the content of this question.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `^77\d{6}$`. Two 7s followed by 6 digits. If `\d` doesn't work in your regex flavor, try `^77[0-9]{6}$`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this Regex:

```
"77\\d{6}"
```